# Double integration in R error

Tags: r

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong in this code?
I am trying to solve this integral in R:

[image: Click here for image]

```
m1 <- 70
m2 <- 70
s1 <- 4
s2 <- 4.5
rho <- 0.25

InnerFunc <- Vectorize(function(x,y) {

  q <- (1/(1-rho^2)) * (((x-m1)/s1)^2 -2 * rho * ((x-m1)/s1) * ((y-m2)/s2) + ((y-m2)/s2)^2)

  Vectorize(function(y){
    0.009136982 * exp(-q/2)
    })
  })

InnerIntegral <- Vectorize(function(x) { 
  Vectorize(function(y) {integrate(InnerFunc, 75, 100)$value})
  })

integrate(InnerIntegral, 75, 100)
```

This leads to the following error message:

```
Error: Error in integrate(InnerIntegral, 75, 100) : 
 evaluation of function gave a result of wrong type
```

Comment: The problem is that `innerFunc()` does not return a numeric value but rather a function. From your question, I don't quite understand what you want to do, so it is difficult to help you further.

Comment: @stibu I am not able to put the equation here. Please check the original post above for an image of the equation I am trying to solve through R.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to define the integrand as a function of two variables as follows:

```
integrand <- function(x, y) {

  m1 <- 70
  m2 <- 70
  s1 <- 4
  s2 <- 4.5
  rho <- 0.25

  q <- (1/(1-rho^2)) * (((x-m1)/s1)^2 -2 * rho * ((x-m1)/s1) * ((y-m2)/s2) + ((y-m2)/s2)^2)
  f <- 1/(2 * pi * 4 * 4.5 * sqrt(1 - 0.0625))

  return (f * exp(-q/2))
}
```

Note that there is no need to use `Vectorize()` here, since arithmetics and `exp()` are vectorized already. The next step is to define another function, where the integral over `y` is executed:

```
integrand2 <- Vectorize(function(x) {
  ix <- function(y) integrand(x, y)
  return (integrate(ix, 75, 100)$value)
})
```

Here, `Vectorize()` is useful, because the function as it stands requires `x` to be a scalar (or, rather, a vector of length 1). Finally, the integration over `x` can be performed:

```
integrate(integrand2, 75, 100)
```